# Are my pageviewcontroller gestures being intercepted?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have followed a pageviewcontroller tutorial to create an image slider.  I have then adapted it to insert into a tableviewcell as I want an image slider within the table.

I like the idea of using this same code in full screen or embedded into another view.

However, when I do this, the pageviewafter and pageviewbefore events dont fire when sliding.  I suspect the tableviewcontroller or cell are gobbling up the events so the pageviewcontroller isnt receiving them.

Im a part time ios developer at best, so looking for any suggestions I can check out/overcome my problem.

Some code detail as requested.  I am adding my PageViewController after a callback of retreiving the images completes.  plantPhotoContainerView is a UIView inside a static cell which was added with the storyboard.

```
self.plantPhotoContainerView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

The pageviewcontroller sets the delegate to itself and I'm currently ignoring the images passed in the controller and just using some test images:

```
class ImageSliderViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    init(images: [String]) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var images = ["Growers", "Home", "Media"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        let imageViewController = ImageViewController()
        imageViewController.imageName = images.first
        let viewControllers = [imageViewController]

        setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentImageName = (viewController as! ImageViewController).imageName!
        let currentIndex = images.firstIndex(of: currentImageName)!

        if currentIndex < images.count - 1 {
            let imageViewController = ImageViewController()
            imageViewController.imageName = images[currentIndex + 1]

            return imageViewController
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentImageName = (viewController as! ImageViewController).imageName!
        let currentIndex = images.firstIndex(of: currentImageName)!

        if currentIndex > 0 {
            let imageViewController = ImageViewController()
            imageViewController.imageName = images[currentIndex - 1]

            return imageViewController
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: fair point, ill edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I eventually found a post which helped.  When adding a subview, two extra lines are required for the default gesture functionality to be passed on through to the pageviewcontroller.  Hope this helps others.

```
self.addChild(vc)
self.plantPhotoContainerView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

To be honest, I don't full understand what this does, maybe someone better versed in the swift framework could elaborate.

Comment: thanks bud.  not sure i see an elaborate description of the problem other than not dancing correctly haha

but i think the most important part is that the view needs to be a child, not just  a subview to behave correctly, good to know and the link elaborates further for other people (y)